# Several roots in one field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm curious as to why, if $r_1$ is a root of $X^4+8X+12$, then no other root can live inside $\mathbb{Q}(r_1)$. This follows immediately from knowledge of the Galois group of $X^4+8X+12$, but are there other methods (apart from inserting $a_1+a_2r_1+a_3r_1^2+a_4r_1^3$ into the polynomial and setting this zero - I know that the polynomial is irreducible)?